# How can I get the elevation of a point in openlayers?

Tags: openlayers-2, api, elevation

I want to know if it is possible to obtain the elevation of a point with some type of control of others. I am painting a linestring with a series of coordinates but I need to know the elevation of every point in order to print a chart. I know that Google has an API for elevation, but I need to use only openlayers.

Note: My baselayer is a google map.

thanks!

Comment: This gets the elevation from the mapquest api on openlayers http://jsfiddle.net/albanlopez/wAXZr/10/

Answer (score 1):

There is a lot of good material on the web:

- **Google Elevation Service:**
  https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/elevation
- **Example 1 - Elevation service example:**
  https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/elevation-simple
- **Example 2 - Showing elevation along a path:**
  https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/elevation-simple
- **Some snippets about Google Elevation Service and OpenLayers:**
  http://lists.osgeo.org/pipermail/openlayers-users/2011-September/022334.html

You only need to glue the right pieces together. Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks very much! but then I understand that openlayers has not his own api for this no?